# Firebase data is not loading on activity loaded

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is my code. I am trying to load firebase data on activity load. The problem is current onchildadded is not working but on child changed is working perfectly. I am new to firebase so i am not being able to figure out the problem. Please help me to fix it. Thank you in advance. :)

```
mydatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(roomname); 
  mydatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        append_chat(dataSnapshot);
                    }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    append_chat(dataSnapshot);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

String data_user_id,data_user_name,data_msg;
    private void append_chat(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext())
        {
            data_user_id = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
            data_user_name = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
            data_msg = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
            mytext.append(data_msg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: try this mydatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tablename").child(roomname);

Comment: @WahdatKashmiri onchildadded() function is not working but onChildChanged() is working perfectly.

Comment: Have u checked the reference and the child names?